# Suppress Warning "API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated"

Tags: polkadot-js

Is there a way to suppress this warning when using Polkadot.js?

```
API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: chainHead_unstable_body, chainHead_unstable_call, chainHead_unstable_follow, chainHead_unstable_genesisHash, chainHead_unstable_header, chainHead_unstable_stopBody, chainHead_unstable_stopCall, chainHead_unstable_stopStorage, chainHead_unstable_storage, chainHead_unstable_unfollow, chainHead_unstable_unpin, mmr_root, mmr_verifyProof, mmr_verifyProofStateless, transaction_unstable_submitAndWatch, transaction_unstable_unwatch
```

Comment: I'm using ``"@polkadot/api": "^9.13.6"``, and I added ``new ApiPromise({ provider, rpc: customRpc, noInitWarn: true });``
but it still display warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. When instatiating your `ApiPromise`, you may pass in `noInitWarn: true` as an option.

Here is the actual field in the [`interface ApiOptions`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/api/src/types/index.ts#L52-L55) type.

Comment: this works. thanks!